# Inject dynamic CSS to a document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

What is the best way to inject dynamic CSS code to a document so that the changes made can be previewed at runtime?

I have a TextArea in an HTML page in which I will type the CSS code. I want to update the styles of the page from the text area. This is the current method I use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic CSS Experiments</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style id="dynamic-css" type="text/css"></style>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var styleTag, textArea;
            styleTag = $("#dynamic-css");
            textArea = $("#css-ta");
            textArea.on('keydown', function () {
                styleTag.html(textArea.val())
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="css" id="css-ta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Is this the best method to do this? Is there any other smart methods?

Comment: What you are doing is perfectly fine and a common approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this to limit the number of updates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic CSS Experiments</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style id="dynamic-css" type="text/css"></style>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var styleTag, textArea, active=true, threashold=100;
            styleTag = $("#dynamic-css");
            textArea = $("#css-ta");
            textArea.on('keydown', function () {
                if (active===true) {
                    active = false;
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        styleTag.html(textArea.val());
                        active = true;
                    }, threashold);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea name="css" id="css-ta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I should think "the best" method is unique for each case.

According to your script, it might be useful to add throttling to the keydown event, so you can reduce the number of updates of your styles and improve performance.

See $.throttle or $.debounce
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/ - example of implementation

Comment: is there any performance issues when updating larger css files ?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a throttle built in (at least built in), are you mixing jQuery with underscore?

Comment: Muhammed K K, when you apply new styles to the document, reflow event is fired. More css updates - more reflows.

Comment: Benjamin Gruenbaum thank you for pointing this out. I added a link to  functions implementation example.

Comment: jQuery has debounce plugin that can reduce the number of updates.
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/

Answer (score 0):

Also, consider jQuery functions: `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` in order to apply CSS styles dynamically.

Comment: its not possible in this case. Here the classes will be over written.

Answer (score 0):

A more improved version would be something like this:

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
        var styleTag, textArea;
        var kI;
        styleTag = $("#dynamic-css");
        textArea = $("#css-ta");
        textArea.on('keyup', function () {
            if (kI !== undefined) {
                 clearTimeout(kI);
            }
            kI = setTimeout(function() {
               styleTag.html(textArea.val());
            },1000);
        });
    });
```

This places a timeout on the keyup event (keyup happens after keydown and prevents repetition for someone keeping a key pressed), to fire 1s after the event has happened. Every time the event happens, the countdown is reset. If the countdown runs its course, your CSS updates.

This avoids too many rewrites of the content of the style block.